# Rails ShopifyAPI::Product does not return total_count, pagination does not worked using shopify-kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify-app, shopify-api

Gem info:

- omniauth-shopify-oauth2 (1.2.0)
- shopify-kaminari (1.1.0)
- shopify_api (4.3.2 494b37a)
- shopify_app (7.4.0)

**Request**:

```
parameters = {fields: 'id,title,url,handle', page: params[:page] || 1, limit: 5}
parameters = parameters.merge(title: params[:title]) if params[:title].present?

@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: parameters)
```

**Issue**:

When requesting **WITH** filter for `title` result doesn't include `total_count`.

Thus `pagination` doesn't worked, doesn't show in view.

```
<%= paginate @items, :pagination_class => 'pagination-centered', params: {title: params[:title], page: params[:page] || 1} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing in the max limit for each request, 250. And then I would use the `#fetch_next_page` method on the collection.

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 250 }
# do something with the products
products.fetch_next_page if products.next_page?
```

This would keep fetching records in batches of 250 until there was no next page, meaning it was the last.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I think the next_page... syntax is only available in latest versions. Also I need to limit 5 products per page.

Comment: Ah, well even if you don't have access to `next_page?` you could still grab the larger limit and paginate that return with something like will_paginate or limit/offset